# Linking slider on my settings page to font on my main page in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I have 3 xaml pages in my visual studio project a MainPage.xaml page, a Homepage.xaml page and a Settings.xaml page, on my Settings page i have a slider for controlling font size which i can bind to TextBlocks on the settings page and change their fontsize but how do i bind it to TextBlocks on my Homepage.xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a shared object that will be refernced to each view for using as data-source. When you creating view you can pass this object to the view via [dependency injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921152.aspx). Your class should implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface to be able to notify clients that a property value has changed.

You can use more commplex and universal solution with [EventAggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx) or other [event-based patterns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745866.aspx). Event aggregator helps to implement subscriber/publisher pattern in low-coupled app.

First create new event with property that you want to send between components (or without any properties if there is no data in this event). In your case this is something like `OnApplicationFontChangedEvent`.

Next subscribe all windows to your event and change your data (`Font` binded to the `Label` or other model property) in event handler with parameter received from handler parameter.

Finally raise (or publish in other terms) your event from your Settings view on button click event handler.

As you can see both of implementations is a part of MVVM libraries and [this pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) can be useful for your app.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply I am trying that approach now.